Why do not I have spot in my SDS-PAGE?
I do a 2-dimensional electrophoresis for a human tissue. My steps were as below:

Whole protein extraction from 4 samples
Protein concentration


Save samples in -20 Frizzier for 3 days


IPG rehydration with 450 micrograms of protein for 18 hour
Isoelectric focusing by Ettan IPGphor3 system (GE Healthcare)
Save IPGs in -20 frizzier for 3 days
SDS PAGE with GE healthcare system on 25 cm Acrylamide/bisacrylamide gels (12%) and ladder input


At the beginning of the SDS PAGE, we had to stop the running several times because of leakage from the upper buffer to the down buffer. Finally, blocking all seams, we successfully ran the SDS PAGE for about 1.5 hours after sitting IPGs on 12% gels.
Problem: Unfortunately after overnight staining by CBB R250 we found no protein spot; however, some smears appeared in the gels.
I want to know why I did not have protein spots in my gels.


You'd need to provide quite a bit more information for us to work out where the problem is - the first thing would be to find out whether your protein samples are degraded or not and the way to do that is to look to see if they migrate in a conventional SDS-PAGE 1-D system.

As I mentioned, The ladder was also smeared in gel. Today, I performed an SDS-PAGE on my protein sample solved in the rehydration buffer. During the SDS-PAGE, I found that the samples moved backward into the upper buffer instead of into the gel. The electrodes were connected correctly. I do not have any idea about this phenomenon.

@mojtabazare IMHO, I would start with the current setup as is and use a common protein of known charge to confirm it was not a machine problem. If the machine is correct, it is likely something with the protein, buffer, or gel.

@Young Jun Lee, The machine works correctly. I want to know which fault made my bad result?!

@mojtabazare I think then, bob1's hypothesis regarding protein sample degradation might be worth considering.

@mojtabazare You didn't mention the ladder was smeared - you mentioned "some smears on gels" but nothing else about smearing that I can see. -20 might not be cold enough to store these proteins. What buffer?, what concentration of protease inhibitors? What were the samples from, incl. which tissue? How did you extract (sonication, homogenization)? All are relevant. You need a lot more details edited into the question to be able to answer.
